# flow_images_from_dataframe function in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, conda, reticulate

I have the images in 2 separate folders (training and testing, no validation as i have few images (406) and the attractiveness ratings (labels) are a column in the dataframe CFDNEW_all_males. Also in CFDNEW_all_males (dataframe) i have the file name id of the model which is (almost) the same as the name of each picture. So reading Deep learning with R by Francois Chollet with J.J. Allaire they use the flow_images_from_directory function. However for my case i found that i can't use that as the labels are stored in the dataframe and should use the flow_images_from_dataframe function setting class_mode = "other" instead of binary because of the regression type of problem. So when i try to run the function i get this error :

Pandas (python module) must be installed in the same environment as Keras.Install it using reticulate::virtualenv_install("pandas", envname = "r-tensorflow") or reticulate::conda_install("pandas", envname = "r-tensorflow") depending on the kind of environment you are using.

code:

```
setwd('/Users/e-mashine/Desktop')
train_image_files_path <- "/Users/e-mashine/Desktop/resized cfd images/training re2"
test_image_files_path <- "/Users/e-mashine/Desktop/resized cfd images/testing re2"
train_files <- list.files(path = train_image_files_path, pattern = "*.jpg", full.names=FALSE)
test_files <- list.files(path = test_image_files_path, pattern = "*.jpg", full.names=FALSE)
for (i in 1:305) {train_dataset$File_Name[i] <- train_files[i]}
for (i in 1:101) {test_dataset$File_Name[i] <- test_files[i]}
train_dataset <- train_dataset[order(train_dataset$File_Name),]
test_dataset <- test_dataset[order(test_dataset$File_Name),]
train_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)    
test_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)
train_generator <- flow_images_from_dataframe(dataframe = train_dataset, directory = train_image_files_path, 
                 x_col = list(train_dataset$File_Name), y_col = list(train_dataset$Attractive), generator = train_datagen,
                 class_mode = "other", target_size = c(640, 450), batch_size = 20, classes = list(train_dataset$Attractive))
```

Error in flow_images_from_dataframe(dataframe = CFDNEW_all_males, directory = train_image_files_path,  :
Pandas (python module) must be installed in the same environment as Keras.Install it using reticulate::virtualenv_install("pandas", envname = "r-tensorflow") or reticulate::conda_install("pandas", envname = "r-tensorflow") depending on the kind of environment you are using.

However, i have done that: (i am using windows so i specify conda)

```
reticulate::conda_install("pandas", envname = "r-tensorflow")
```

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

All requested packages already installed.

Lastly i have also done that (before):

```
install.packages("reticulate")
library(reticulate)
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(version = "2.5.0", method = "conda", envname = "r-reticulate")
library(tensorflow)
tf_config()
```

2021-07-10 14:30:29.462901: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-07-10 14:30:29.464762: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
TensorFlow v2.5.0 ()
Python v3.7 (C:/Users/e-mashine/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe)

I also tryied:

```
reticulate::virtualenv_install("pandas", envname = "r-tensorflow")
```

but same error as above...
Any help?

**EDIT**: I used a custom function and it worked however i got this error when i try to look at the output of one of these generators:

```
# custom function, this works..
flow_images_from_dataframe<-function (dataframe, 
directory=NULL,x_col="filename",y_col="class",generator = 
image_data_generator(),target_size = c(640,450), color_mode = "rgb", 
classes = NULL, class_mode = "other", batch_size = 32, shuffle = TRUE, 
seed = NULL, save_to_dir = NULL, save_prefix = "", save_format = 
"jpg",dtype="float32",
subset = NULL, interpolation = "nearest",drop_duplicates=TRUE) 
{args <- list(dataframe=as.data.frame(dataframe), directory = 
normalizePath(directory), #directory = as.character(directory),  
x_col=x_col,y_col=y_col,target_size = as.integer(target_size), 
color_mode = color_mode, classes = classes, class_mode = class_mode, 
batch_size = as.integer(batch_size), shuffle = shuffle, seed = NULL, 
           #as_nullable_integer(seed),
           #save_to_dir = normalizePath(save_to_dir),
           save_to_dir = NULL,
           save_prefix = save_prefix, save_format = 
           save_format,dtype=dtype, 
           drop_duplicates=drop_duplicates)
 #if (keras_version() >= "2.1.2") 
 #  args$interpolation <- interpolation
 #if (keras_version() >= "2.1.5") 
 # args$subset <- subset
 #do.call(generator$flow_from_dataframe, args)
 }
environment(flow_images_from_dataframe) <- asNamespace('keras')
batch <- generator_next(train_generator, completed = NULL)
#Error: object is not iterable

str(batch)
#Error: object 'batch' not found
```

it should be  num [20, 1:640, 1:450, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
and a list of 2?

Answer (score 1):

I think this was fixed in a recent version of keras package. If you're still experiencing this issue, please file an issue here: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/new